# Send httpclient 4.3.5 request with local address ip

Tags: java, httpclient

So, I searched all over the place but have not found an answer that really works. Here is my issue, I want to make a httpClient request setting a local address:

`HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
Builder myReqBuilder = RequestConfig.custom().setLocalAddress(InetAddress.getByName(//myIp//);
httpClientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(myReqBuilder.build());
//Other stuff, not important//
this.httpClient = httpClientBuilder.setConnectionManager(this.getConnectionManager()).build();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("http://server.com"), new BasicHttpContext())`

Somethings are figurative :P

* If I put as myIp my ip address I receive as exception: "java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address"
* If i put "localhost", I get: "Connect to /*server*/ failed: Invalid argument"

Either way it doesn't work 
Why doesn't it work?

Comment: display your local '/etc/hosts' file looking for "localhost" ip addr......  try connecting to  that  $myIPadd:$localPort  ( assume that you are running a local instance of apache or nginx which listens on $localPort from the above )   usually , it will be "127.0.0.1"   so your domain for the httpclient would be "127.0.0.1:8080"

Comment: Well.. I don't know why using "localhost" as my ip doesn't resolve anything; but when I put my inner ip (not the onw that whatsmyip gives me) **it worked**